# Getting MUC messages from ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, muc

I am building a chat application using ejabberd.

I am using `mod_mam` from master repo. I am having 1-1 as well as MUC.

I am not able to query the MUC messages from the archive and it always gives 0 results. I have verified that the messages are getting archived in database. So I suspect it is the request for MUC messages, which is wrong.

Below is the request XML which is going and resulting in 0 results.

```
<iq type="set" id="333_vishal007@localhost"><query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:1"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"><value>urn:xmpp:mam:1</value></field><field var="with"><value>group@conference.localhost</value></field></x></query></iq>
```

Can someone please tell me the right request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of ejabberd are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

MAM queries for MUC archives should have room JID in `to` atrtribute

Comment: If I do that then I get feature not implemented error. Do I need any configuration? Can you post me sample request XML?? Thanks for the help.